# how to init jquery ui from requirejs when jquery is already loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint, requirejs

I was trying to use jquery ui in a sharepoint project and since the jquery is already loaded I don't see the reason of requiring it again when I need the accordion from jquery ui.

I already followed all the steps and added the folders to work with require js. as in:
https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/amd/

but I still get the same error:

```
Script error for "jquery", needed by: jqueryui/widgets/accordion, jqueryui/version, jqueryui/keycode, jqueryui/unique-id, jqueryui/widget
```

here is my code:

```
  function main() {
    require({
      paths: {
        jqueryui: '/teams/sp-test-site/dist/jQuery/ui/1.12.1',
      },
      shim: {
        deps: [ 'jquery', ],
      },
    }, [ 'jqueryui/widgets/accordion', ],
    function (accordion) {
      $('#accordion').accordion();
    });
  }

  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('require.js', null, main);
  }, 'core.js');
```

So I assume I am missing some init function to use the already loaded jquery from the globals, I am just not sure how, if it is the case. Does any body know what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

defining jquery and returning the global one solved.

```
define('jquery', [], function () {
          return window.jQuery;
        });
```